# Spring boot war file exception when running more than one Spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm facing a very strange issue. When I create a war file with Spring Tools Suit and deploy it to Tomcat everything works fine. But if I deploy another Spring Boot war file (a different Spring boot project), then the latest one will throw exceptions. But as long as only one of them is uploaded, then they will both work fine with no exceptions.

Below are the exceptions I get from one of the war files. This only occurs if I have another war file deployed on Tomcat, the generated logs are too long to post here so I posted them here

https://pastebin.com/6rnAsWT8

Below is the server information

```
root@localhost:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin# ./version.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14 (Debian)
Server built:   Sep 3 2017 17:51:58 UTC
Server number:  8.5.14.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.9.0-6-amd64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-1~deb9u1-b11
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Below is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.imageapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ImageAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ImageAPI</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

And below is the changes I made for the project to work as war file when uploaded to Tomcat

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ImageApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ImageApiApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ImageApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://serverup:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=mydb
spring.datasource.password=mypass
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.security.user.name=myusername
spring.security.user.password=mypass

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

spring.application.name=imageapi
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Did you also update your configuration in your Spring boot application to accommodate it running as a war?

Comment: yes, both projects work fine as long as they are the only war file deployed to Tomcat.

Comment: as for the jmx instance already exists exception

Checkout this link -

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/118

Comment: Use might have two beans with same id as log is throwing `Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource` check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466851/javax-management-instancealreadyexistsexception-while-deploying-spring-applicati

Comment: @IndraneelBende that does seem to be the same issue that I'm having but their solution is for Gradle? I am using maven and I don't have the file src/main/resources/application.yml

Comment: how are u managing ur configurations?

Comment: I use this file src/main/resources/application.properties

Comment: well u can just specify the property then in the properties file in each of those applications. Your errors related to instance already exists will go away then.

Comment: I added it to both projects, recreated the war file, again the first war file got deployed and started with no issues, but the second one is throwing exceptions https://pastebin.com/HCXtsy8m I also added my `application.properties` to the question

Comment: check line no 228. Looks like ur data source definition is getting overriden. There seems to be already a bean in the same jvm. Are you creating a data source bean in both applications ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171898/discussion-between-indraneel-bende-and-arya).

Comment: It works now, turns out I needed two things added to application.properties  `spring.application.name=imageapi` and
 `spring.jmx.default-domain=imageapi` you may post this as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Please avoid using external sites(pastebin, etc) for posting useful information like stacktrace. People who are willing to help you might be behind corporate firewall and may not be able to access those sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving a JMX InstanceAlreadyExists Exception. Specify unique values for the following properties in each Application

```
          spring.application.name
          spring.jmx.default-domain
```

Hope this helps.